# How to upload Vendor folder using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I am trying to deploy Laravel project using bitbucket pipeline. With this code:

```
pipelines:
  custom: 
    staging-init:
      - step:
          name: 'Init'
          image: php:7.3-fpm
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-ftp
            - git ftp init --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS $FTP_PATH
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: 'Deploy'
          image: php:7.3-fpm
          script: 
            - apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-ftp
            - git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS $FTP_PATH
      - step:
          name: 'Composer'
          image: php:7.3-fpm
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
            - apt-get update && apt-get -y install git-ftp
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - cp .env.example .env
            - composer install
            - php artisan key:generate
            - git ftp push --syncroot ./vendor --force --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASS $FTP_PATH
```

I also created .git-ftp-include file with this code:

```
!./vendor
```

But it ignores the vendor folder. What can I try to upload vendor folder?

Comment: I don't know what ftp is doing here, but why not run composer install instead?

Comment: I'm using bitbucket pipelines to auto deploy files to server through ftp because I don't have ssh data to make this posible with jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question about how to upload a folder via FTP for a deployment in a bitbucket-pipelines context, I can only suggest you try out the atlassian/ftp-deploy pipe and drop de git-ftp command.

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: build your app here
          artifacts:
            - vendor
            - ????
          script:
            - composer install
            - ????
      - step:
          name: deploy
          deployment: production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.7
              variables:
                USER: $FTP_USER
                PASSWORD: $FTP_PASS
                SERVER: ????  # this can be set per deployment stage!
                REMOTE_PATH: $FTP_PATH
```

See https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/ftp-deploy

---

On why your git-ftp is dysfunctional, you should better use the git-ftp tag!